# Switching underlaying view controllers iOS 8

Tags: ios, ios8, modalviewcontroller

This is the goal :

I have a navigation controller (NC1), that is presenting modally some view controller (VC). When I do some action in that view controller, I need to (invisibly for the user) dismiss VC, dismiss NC1, then present another navigation controller (NC2) and present the same view controller VC.

In iOS 7.0, 7.1 this is working well via this (slightly adjusted) code:

```
  [controller dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];   //dismiss VC
  [self.presentedViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil]; //dismiss NC1

  SomeViewController * someViewController = [[SomeViewController alloc] init];  // root vc for NC2    
  NavigationController * navigationController = [[NavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:someViewController];     //NC2

  SomeViewController2 * someViewController2 = [[SomeViewController2 alloc] init];  
  [navigationController presentSomehow:someViewController2 animated:NO completion:nil]; //another pushed to NC2

  [someViewController2 presentViewController:controller animated:NO completion:nil]; //present VC again
```

but in iOS 8 (Xcode 6.0) it seems that even after dismissing, VC remains active and the app crashes at the last line with:

> Application tried to present modally an active controller ...

And of course if I move the code to completion blocks the changes are visible to user (and ugly).

*Is there a way to check or force the VC to leave the active state, or some other way to simulate the iOS 7 behavior?*

Thanks for answers!

Comment: Why do you need to switch Navigation controllers?   Are they navigation controller subclasses?  If not then one is the same as the other.

Comment: What is the effect you are after here? Why do you think you have to switch navigation controllers?

Comment: Well they are the same subclass of navigation controller, but I need the second one to have different root controller..
I might add that the navigation controller itself is presented modally.

Comment: You can just modify the stack through the `viewControllers` property (or the `setViewControllers:animated` method)

Comment: Didn't think of that, as I was too focused on finding some general approach for switching them. Thanks, this solved my problem